# VB.NET file error 75 - Path/File Access Error - how is my file locked? I need to delete it

Tags: vb.net, file, locking

i'm getting a error 75 - file/path access error when i attempt to delete my file (last lines of the code block below):

```
        ' make a reference to a directory
    Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(WatchDirectory) 'ex C:\Print\Realtime\
    Dim directoryList As IO.FileInfo() = directory.GetFiles(WatchFilter) 'ex *.xml
    Dim directoryFile As IO.FileInfo

    'list the names of all files in the specified directory
    For Each directoryFile In directoryList
        'scans the Realtime folder (WatchDirectory) for each specified file (WatchFilter / xml) for processing.
        If directoryFile.Name = RealTimeFile Then
            'checks if the file is realtime by matching the name up to the ProcessRealtimeFile app setting (ex realtime.xml)
            Continue For
        Else
            'this is not a ProcessRealtimeFile app setting (ex realtime.xml) file
            Dim Name As String
            Dim renameRetries As Integer = 5

            'get file name without extension
            Name = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(directoryFile.Name)

            While True
                Try
                    If File.Exists(ProcessDirectory & RealTimeFile) = False Then
                        'the current file to be checked against in the watch directory does not exist in the processdirectory (ex. C:\Print\Oracle\xml.rt\). continue.
                        Log.Write(Log.Level.Information, "RTPrint-Diamond", Environment.UserName, Environment.MachineName, "File " & directoryFile.FullName & " is being processed by scrape.")

                        If ArchiveXML = True Then
                            'copy the current file to the archive directory (ex C:\print\xml.rt\archive\), overwriting the existing file if exists
                            System.IO.File.Copy(directoryFile.FullName, ArchiveDirectory & directoryFile.Name, True)
                        End If

                        'update the date and time of the active file to now
                        System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTime(directoryFile.FullName, Date.Now)
                        Log.Write(Log.Level.Information, "RTPrint-Diamond", Environment.UserName, Environment.MachineName, "Date Changed.")

                        If ISPublisher(directoryFile.FullName) Then
                            'Current file is a publisher file. Process
                            Dim fileInfo As New IO.FileInfo(directoryFile.FullName)
                            Dim utf8WithoutBOM As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding(False) 'file encoding type - UTF8 w/o BOM

                            Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Path.Combine(PublisherProcessDirectory, directoryFile.Name), False, utf8WithoutBOM)
                                'set up write to the publisher process directory (ex C:\print5x\xml.rt\)
                                'publisher requires utf8 w/o BOM to read the file. We need to change the encoding type to this standard.
                                'this converts the file to utf8 w/o BOM to the 5x output destination
                                Using reader As StreamReader = fileInfo.OpenText
                                    While Not reader.EndOfStream
                                        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine
                                        writer.Write(line & vbCrLf)
                                    End While
                                    reader.Close()
                                End Using
                                writer.Close()
                            End Using

                            If File.Exists(Path.Combine(PublisherProcessDirectory, directoryFile.Name)) Then
                                'make sure the destination file was successfully re-written in utf8 w/o bom and delete the source file
                                If IsFileOpen(directoryFile.FullName, 1) = True Then
                                    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileClose(1)
                                End If

                                System.IO.File.Delete(directoryFile.FullName)
                            End If
```

I even tested with some sample solutions I read on this site to run a function test to see if the lock is present (giving error 75), and if true is returned, attempt a file close which also is not doing anything.

Obviously my `writer.Close()` is not doing the job. Can anyone spot why the `System.IO.File.Delete(directoryFile.FullName)` is not allowing me access to this text file for deletion, and how i can unlock it to delete? Is it the for each that is locking my file?  I need to delete the file within the loop, so if the for loop is locking me, what are the work-arounds here?

Additionally, i tested the delete by removing the entire writer block and 2 declared variables above it, and the file still had a lock. This can help to isolate the issue to the surrounding logic and not the `streamWriter` portion.

Thanks in advance!